# Why we want the string to be massless in the ideal model of simple pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, string, oscillators

[image]

I couldn't think about a reason why the string must be massless. Wouldn't the assumption that the air resistance is negligible, the angle $\theta$ is small and the string is non-stretchable suffice for our derivation of the simple pendulum?

Comment: It would then become a physical pendulum : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum#Compound_pendulum

Answer (score 3):

Introducing a massless string is a way to avoid dealing with the string as a part of the dynamic system and using its presence only as of the source of a constraint on the oscillating mass motion.

Indeed, assigning a mass to the string and taking into account its equations of motion would result in a system equivalent to a pendulum with a massless string but with a different length $l'<l$.